# Ways to keep the same header on every page of the website

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, master-pages

I am trying to make a member based website in which I will need to keep the HEADER and certain other elements fixed on every page of the site.
I am familiar with the concept of MasterPages in Asp.net, and SHTML however I find it a bit confusing and tedious to use them for a website.
I want to know that are their some other ways to achieve the same feat in a way other than SHTML or MasterPages, one that is more refined and easy to implement?

Comment: you can use User Control also for Header.

Comment: is there any problem using `Masterpage` ?

Comment: @zey, No problem in using them, but i am pretty sure that major websites don't use that concept, right?

Comment: Why would you think that?

Comment: @OskarDuveborn, I think they are sort of bulky. Plus it is a MS technology, so why would google or facebook even implement it, though there might be some other way, and that's what I wanna know.

Comment: You're already on an MS stack so that doesn't make any sense. MasterPage isn't a concept perse but simply an easy way to set up one or more page templates that you can render on multiple pages without hassle in ASP.NET. Google or Facebook wouldn't use ASP.NET User Controls either in that context. The client will never know there was a MasterPage.

Comment: Facebook is built in PHP, so they probably use #includes or whatever

Answer (score 2):

Create User Control In your Application and Register Your User Control in your Page(like  .aspx).

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UC" Src="~/UserControl.ascx" TagName="mycontrol" %>
```

and Use Like control.

```
<UC:mycontrol ID="my" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get acquainted with the concept of UserControls. Read here for a complete understanding: [MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

User controls are  powerful functionality of ASP.NET. With the help of the user control you can reuse the Design as well as code in the application.

This another link provides very basic introduction of UserControls and finally ends up creating a one:http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using a perl script that concatenates header/content/footer files together. However this is a bit OTT so I am in the process of converting to iframes. All you need do is add a line to the top of each page...

```
<iframe border=0 src="http://mysite.com/header.html"></iframe>
```

You can adjust the size of the frame if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like master pages, you could always try Dreamweaver templates, which auto generates the template contents on each page using the templates.